# .NET - Is disabling IIf possible?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We have had a problem in our code with people using `IIf()` where they should really be using `If`.

Is there a way I can override `IIf` to disable it, or make it obsolete by using the `<Obsolete()>` tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll from the project references.

[image]

Then you can't use the VB6 functions.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! For reference, I've also found a crib sheet for .NET equivalent functions: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Visual_Basic_6_to_.NET_Function_Equivalents